# How can we deploy vespa.ai application on multiple docker container running on separate instances using kubernetes?

Tags: vespa

I need to deploy Vespa.ai docker containers on multiple instances (3) using kubernetes. What configuration changes do I have to do in my application package or in docker so that I can run the admin node, container node, content node on separate instances?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are your results ? Some examples please of the work that you have already under taken would help other SO users better understand the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

See this guide for how to deploy a multi node Vespa cluster on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/basic-search-on-gke.